# EventListener não esta sendo removido

Tags: javascript, event-listener

Olá, criei um botão em HTML com a ID definada como "random" o qual quando apertado altera constantemente o valor de uma variável para que possa ser utilizada em um outro evento:

```
let colorSelector = document.querySelector("#color-selector")
let randomColor = document.querySelector("#random")

randomColor.addEventListener("click", randomizer, true)
function randomizer() {
    let colors = ['#1038d5', '#8610d5', '#d510c5', '#d51079', '#d51010', '#d57910', '#bed510', '#3bd510', '#10d579', '#10a4d5']
    setInterval(() => {
        color = colors[Math.round(Math.random() * 10 - 1)]
    })
}
```

Entretanto, a função permanece ativa quando tento selecionar uma cor de forma manual (input do tipo color) após já ter apertado no botão. Também tentei remover o EventListener mas o problema persiste.

```
colorSelector.addEventListener("change", () => {
    randomColor.removeEventListener("click", randomizer, true)
    color = colorSelector.value
})
```

- O interessante é que se eu selecionar a cor de forma manual antes de clicar no botão, a função randomizer() que gera valores aleatórios não vai funcionar.
- Nenhum erro é retornado.

Sabem me dizer por qual motivo isso ocorre? Será que não funciona pois há outro evento de fundo? Enfim, agradeço desde já.

Answer (score 0):

Descobri que o problema era o setTimeout. Para poder interrompê-lo era necessário atribuí-lo em uma variável de escopo global nesse caso (global pois o clearInterval é chamado em um outro eventListener). *Por favor, ignorem o nome dado.*

```
let intervalo
randomColor.addEventListener("click",randomizer)
function randomizer() {
    intervalo = setInterval(() => {
        let colors = ['#1038d5', '#8610d5', '#d510c5', '#d51079', '#d51010', '#d57910', '#bed510', '#3bd510', '#10d579', '#10a4d5']
        color = colors[Math.round(Math.random() * 10 - 1)]
    })
}
```

Assim, conseguindo encerrar sem problema algum:

```
let colorSelector = document.querySelector("#color-selector")
colorSelector.addEventListener("change", () => {
    color = colorSelector.value
    clearInterval(intervalo)
})
```